# I tried by converting it into int also then also same error

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, image-classification

Face/mask detection model is work good but I want to count fps to compare to different models for better performance metrics. This is my OpenCV code:

```
def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image=frame, scalefactor=1.0,size=(300,300),
                                mean=(104.0,177.0,123.0),swapRB=True,crop=True)
    print("Shape of input blob: {}\n".format(input_blob.shape))
    
    #pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
    
    faceNet.setInput(input_blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    print(detections.shape)
    
    #initialize our list of faces, with thir corresponding locations and list of predictions from mask data
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []
    
    #loop over the detections
    
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        
        #extract the probability associated with detection
        confidence = detections[0,0, i,2]
        
        #remove the weak detections by ensuring the probability is greater than min probability
        if confidence > 0.5:
            #compute the (x, y)-coordinates of  rectanlge for the obejct
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
            
            #make sure rectangle fall within the diemensions of frame
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w-1, endX), min(h -1, endY))
            
            #extract the face region of intrest(ROI), convert it from BGR to RGB channel and resize to 224x224 and preprocess it
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (300,300))
            face = img_to_array(face)#we convert pixel format to numpy array format
            face =preprocess_input(face)
            
            #add face and bounding box to lists
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
            
    #run the predictions only when at least in person is was detected
    if len(faces) > 0:
        #we make group predictions at one time rather than at one by one
        
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)
        
    #return a 2-tuple of the face locations and their corresponding
    #locs is the x and y coordinates of the rectangle that's going to surround the face
    #preds are given the percentage of accuracy while in a detection operation
    return (locs, preds)

#load our preloaded face detector model from drive
prototxtpath = r"face-detection-opencv\deploy.prototxt.txt"
weightspath = r"face-detection-opencv\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
facenet=cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtpath, weightspath)

#Now load our trained mask detection model
maskNet = load_model(r"detection_MobilenetV2_300_300.h5")

#set up the video stream
print("Seting up the video stream...")
cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

start_time = time.time()
# FPS update time in seconds
display_time = 2
fc = 0
FPS = 0

#loop over the frames from the video stream
while True:
    #grab the frme from the video stream and resize is to have maximum widht of 800 pixels
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=800)
    fc+=1
    TIME = time.time()-start_time

    if(TIME)>=display_time:
        FPS=fc/(TIME)
        fc=0
        start_time=time.time()

    fps_disp = "FPS: "+str(FPS)[:5]
    #detect and predict in video if they wearing mask or not
    
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, facenet, maskNet)
     # time when we finish processing for this frame

    #loop over the detected face locations
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        #zip function is used when you have the mutiple iteration argumetns in singel loop
        #unpack the rectangle box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        #define the color of the rectangle accroding the prediction adn dectection of the video stream and also lable of the detection
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label=="Mask" else (0,0,255)

        #include the accuracy percentage 
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask)*100)

     
        cv2.putText(frame,fps_disp, (10, 25),label,(startX, startY - 10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(startX, startY),(endX, endY), color, 2)

        #show the output 

        cv2.imshow("FRAME",'Video Stream w/ FPS', frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
   
    
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
        
# cleanup and closing frame

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Error message:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-fcfad49a5f36> in <module>
    115 
    116 
--> 117         cv2.putText(frame,fps_disp, (10, 25),label,(startX, startY - 10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
    118         cv2.rectangle(frame,(startX, startY),(endX, endY), color, 2)
    119 

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I also converted to integer but same error repeats
[image:Error message on notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcYn.jpg)

Comment: The parameters you're passing to `cv2.putText` don't make any sense -- you're setting colour to `cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX`, font face to some label, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

it might be the mismatching the order

try to label input when you call the function

Syntax:

```
cv2.putText(image, text, org, font, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]])
```

like

```
cv2.putText(image=frame,text=fps_disp ....)
```

i had the same problem and it help me